# Facing problem to change dataframe structure due to special characters

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

My Input Data set is

```
df1 = data.frame(Var_A = c('A&B X+Y','C S'),
                 Var_B = c('1,2','2'))
```

Desired Output is

```
df2 = data.frame(Var_A = c('A&B','A&B','X+Y','X+Y','C S'),
                 Var_B = c('1','2','1','2','2'))
```

Presence of special character such as "&","+" and Space is posing problem

The code I am using is

```
test_new = separate_rows(df1, "Var_B", convert = FALSE) %>%
  separate_rows("Var_A") %>%
  arrange(Var_A)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can specify the `sep` in `separate_rows` with a regex lookaround

```
df1 %>% 
   separate_rows(Var_B) %>% 
   separate_rows(Var_A, sep= "(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z][+])") %>%
   arrange(Var_A)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I was able to solve the same.

Comment: What if the input  data set is like                                        df1 = data.frame(Var_A = c('A&B , X+Y','C S'),
                 Var_B = c('1,2','2')) and desired output is                                          
 df2 = data.frame(Var_A = c('A&B','A&B','X+Y','X+Y','C S'),
                 Var_B = c('1','2','1','2','2'))

Comment: @AmanSaddi Then you may need the `sep` as `sep= "(?<=[A-Z]) , (?=[A-Z][+])") `